# scrollTop stuck at zero

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the vertical position on scroll of page but it is stuck at `0` value.

```
window.onscroll=f;
function f() {

document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

Comment: Are you scrolling back up to the top of the page to read `div1`, perchance? :)

Comment: there are several elements scrolling and this can be a mess: check window, <html> and <body>.

Comment: There is no change in value.... either scroll any way

Comment: @sandbox: it works for me in Chrome.  Which browsers have you tested?

Comment: @AndyE I tested on a new page with 1 div and it works... but not on my website with around 50+ divs....? Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use something like

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=document.documentElement.scrollTop ? 
document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop
```

Comment: Should probably test for the existence of document.documentElement, rather than document.documentElement.scrollTop. I believe trying to access a property of something undefined will throw an error.

Comment: @Jordan: `document.documentElement` will always be defined for a (X|HT)ML document.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `document.documentElement.scrollTop` when I should have been using `window.pageYOffset`.